# Dropdown menu item hide when click away?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

I have a [fiddle](http://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/jPXoYq) for my project. I'm making a responsive navigation with dropdown menus. I currently have the dropdown items set to toggle when you click them. However, I'd like the dropdown to close if you click anywhere away from it.

I tried copying the code from a similar question, but it isn't working for me. I included it in the fiddle, but commented out so you can see the dropdowns work.

```
$(document).click(function(){
  $(".nav-dropdown").hide();
});

$(".nav-dropdown").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the `e.stopPropagation()` inside the toggle function.

Here is the working fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwLoKE

(If you want to have just one dropdown opened at a time, you'll also have to close the opened ones inside you toggle function.)

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you! Works great. If you could provide a hint towards how to close one dropdown when another opens, that would also be really cool.  (I'm exceedingly new to jQuery and JavaScript). Otherwise I'll be working on figuring that out.

Comment: I let you figure out the exact code, but the concept is that inside the toggle function, first query for any opened dropdown, close it, and then toggle the one you clicked.

Comment: I used  `$('.nav-dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();` and it seems to work!